# Hapi JS post request payload parsing issue

Tags: node.js, express, node-modules, hapi.js

I am using `HapiJS 11` and now upgrading it to `HapiJS 16`. While updating I am facing an issue related to payload parsing.

In `HapiJS 11` I am getting payload as

```
{
 "profile":{
   "name": <name>,
   "email": <email>
 }
}
```

but in `HapiJS 16` I am getting is as

```
{
 "profile[name]": <name>,
 "profile[email]": <email>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for the problem.

Actually from version 13 `Hapi JS` has removed parsing query parameters, payload data as a core functionality, to parse these we need to add a plugin [hapi-qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hapi-qs) with `hapi`.

Source: [Hapi 13 release summary](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/2985)

Other Sources:

https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/1317

https://github.com/hapijs/discuss/issues/425